ViaVersion issue on private server
My server is running James Chambers modded MC that allows PC and Console players to play together.
Recently, there are issues with getting things updated or running. ViaVersion has been a nightmare.
James has stopped responding to any and all questions. I'm presuming that he's moved on to other endeavors, which is fine. He's not obligated to continue support for this thing he created for free.
When trying to get the server up and running, I am getting the following:
Loading libraries, please wait...
[17:53:57 ERROR]: [DirectoryProviderSource] Error loading plugin: Directory 'plugins/ViaVersion.jar' failed to load!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Directory 'plugins/ViaVersion.jar' failed to load!
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:59) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.lambda$registerProviders$1(DirectoryProviderSource.java:34) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1921) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[?:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:32) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.DirectoryProviderSource.registerProviders(DirectoryProviderSource.java:14) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.util.EntrypointUtil.registerProvidersFromSource(EntrypointUtil.java:14) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.PluginInitializerManager.load(PluginInitializerManager.java:100) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(Main.java:137) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main.main(Main.java:324) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paperclip.Paperclip.lambda$main$0(Paperclip.java:42) ~[app:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.checkUpdate(FileProviderSource.java:95) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:49) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1483) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1491) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1329) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1292) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:710) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:345) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:316) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:282) ~[?:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.getPluginName(FileProviderSource.java:101) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.checkUpdate(FileProviderSource.java:76) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.provider.source.FileProviderSource.registerProviders(FileProviderSource.java:49) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        ... 20 more
[17:54:01 INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[17:54:03 INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[17:54:04 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.20.1
[17:54:04 WARN]: ****************************
[17:54:04 WARN]: YOU ARE RUNNING THIS SERVER AS AN ADMINISTRATIVE OR ROOT USER. THIS IS NOT ADVISED.
[17:54:04 WARN]: YOU ARE OPENING YOURSELF UP TO POTENTIAL RISKS WHEN DOING THIS.
[17:54:04 WARN]: FOR MORE INFORMATION, SEE https://madelinemiller.dev/blog/root-minecraft-server/
[17:54:04 WARN]: ****************************
[17:54:04 INFO]: Loading properties
[17:54:04 INFO]: This server is running Paper version git-Paper-196 (MC: 1.20.1) (Implementing API version 1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT) (Git: 773dd72)
[17:54:04 INFO]: Server Ping Player Sample Count: 12
[17:54:04 INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
[17:54:04 WARN]: [!] The timings profiler has been enabled but has been scheduled for removal from Paper in the future.
    We recommend installing the spark profiler as a replacement: https://spark.lucko.me/
    For more information please visit: https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/issues/8948
[17:54:04 INFO]: [ChunkTaskScheduler] Chunk system is using 1 I/O threads, 2 worker threads, and gen parallelism of 2 threads
[17:54:05 ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.SerializationException: [entities, spawning, monster-spawn-max-light-level] of type java.lang.Integer: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "default"
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.parseNumber(NumericSerializers.java:346) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.lambda$static$9(NumericSerializers.java:254) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.FunctionScalarSerializer.deserialize(FunctionScalarSerializer.java:40) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.ScalarSerializer.deserialize(ScalarSerializer.java:115) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.AbstractConfigurationNode.get(AbstractConfigurationNode.java:151) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.get(ConfigurationNode.java:520) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.require(ConfigurationNode.java:407) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.configuration.Configurations.initializeWorldDefaultsConfiguration(Configurations.java:154) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:210) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1100) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:317) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
        Suppressed: org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.SerializationException: [entities, behavior, zombie-villager-infection-chance] of type java.lang.Double: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "default"
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.lambda$static$3(NumericSerializers.java:144) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.FunctionScalarSerializer.deserialize(FunctionScalarSerializer.java:40) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.ScalarSerializer.deserialize(ScalarSerializer.java:115) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.AbstractConfigurationNode.get(AbstractConfigurationNode.java:151) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.get(ConfigurationNode.java:520) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.require(ConfigurationNode.java:407) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                at io.papermc.paper.configuration.Configurations.initializeWorldDefaultsConfiguration(Configurations.java:154) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
                at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:210) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
                at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1100) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
                at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:317) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "default"
                at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054) ~[?:?]
                at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[?:?]
                at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:735) ~[?:?]
                at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.lambda$static$3(NumericSerializers.java:142) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
                ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "default"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665) ~[?:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.parseNumber(NumericSerializers.java:344) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        ... 20 more
[17:54:05 ERROR]:       Cause of unexpected exception was
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "default"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665) ~[?:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.parseNumber(NumericSerializers.java:344) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.NumericSerializers.lambda$static$9(NumericSerializers.java:254) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.FunctionScalarSerializer.deserialize(FunctionScalarSerializer.java:40) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.serialize.ScalarSerializer.deserialize(ScalarSerializer.java:115) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load0(ObjectMapperImpl.java:64) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperImpl.load(ObjectMapperImpl.java:48) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.objectmapping.ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.deserialize(ObjectMapperFactoryImpl.java:204) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.AbstractConfigurationNode.get(AbstractConfigurationNode.java:151) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.get(ConfigurationNode.java:520) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at org.spongepowered.configurate.ConfigurationNode.require(ConfigurationNode.java:407) ~[configurate-core-4.1.2.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.configuration.Configurations.initializeWorldDefaultsConfiguration(Configurations.java:154) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:210) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1100) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:317) ~[paper-1.20.1.jar:git-Paper-196]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[?:?]
[17:54:05 ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: /minecraft/./crash-reports/crash-2024-12-18_17.54.05-server.txt
[17:54:05 INFO]: Stopping server
[17:54:05 INFO]: Saving players
[17:54:05 INFO]: Saving worlds
[17:54:05 INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage: All dimensions are saved
[17:54:05 INFO]: Flushing Chunk IO
2024-12-18 17:54:05,263 Log4j2-AsyncAppenderEventDispatcher-1-Async WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
[17:54:05 INFO]: Closing Thread Pool
[17:54:05 INFO]: Closing Server

I have downloaded the latest version of ViaVersion, and this still happens.
Any thoughts?

Try changing monster-spawn-max-light-level and zombie-villager-infection-chance in paper-world.yml to an integer/number
make moster... as 7 and zombie villager.... as 80 and check if it works
also use latest viaversion(5.2.0 as of now)
